# Is it possible to connect zend framework 1 with latest Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework

Language: PHP
Framework: Zend Framework 1
Database: mySql

I have an existing project in Zend Framework 1 and in this project we send a mail in foreach loop but I want to send mail using Laravel queue-job functionality. Is this possible to listen database table?

Thank you In advance.

If we create one model for existing table and use the model static function created and fire some event or anything else.

Comment: One solution could be to create a json api on your ZF1 application and then get the email address in your laravel application

Comment: @SergioRinaudo Thanks! We just make one API in Laravel. we are using the same database which we are using in zend so when we click on send mail then inform laravel and it will work like Laravel queue-job functionality.

Comment: @SergioRinaudo Do we have any other option?

Comment: There can be lots of solutions, for example the ZF1 functionality can be edited and the email stored in some dbtable replacing the sending loop, then processed by Laravel